# Pycharm Inpection profile importing is not working

Tags: import, pycharm, inspection

I tried to import a XML file for Inspection setting in Pycharm.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiaKw.png)
As you can see, there is no 'Import' option which is supposed to be there at the very bottom of the list.
How can I enable this?

Erasing whole Pycharm
Re-installing Pycharm